# How to count co-ocurrences with collections.Counter() in python?

Tags: python, collections, counter

I learned about the [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class recently and, as it's a neat (and fast??) way to count stuff, I started using it.

But I detected a bug on my program recently due to the fact that when I try to update the count with a tuple, it actually treats it as a sequence and *updates the count for each item in the tuple* instead of counting *how many times I inserted that particular tuple*.

For example, if you run:

```
import collections
counter = collections.Counter()
counter.update(('user1', 'loggedin'))
counter.update(('user2', 'compiled'))
counter.update(('user1', 'compiled'))

print counter
```

You'll get:

```
Counter({'compiled': 2, 'user1': 2, 'loggedin': 1, 'user2': 1})
```

as a result. Is there a way to count tuples with the Counter()? I could concatenate the strings but this is... ugly. Could I use named tuples? Implement my own very simple dictionary counter? Don't know what's best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure: you simply have to add one level of indirection, namely pass `.update` a container with the tuple as an element.

```
>>> import collections
>>> counter = collections.Counter()
>>> counter.update((('user1', 'loggedin'),))
>>> counter.update((('user2', 'compiled'),))
>>> counter.update((('user1', 'compiled'),))
>>> counter.update((('user1', 'compiled'),))
>>> counter
Counter({('user1', 'compiled'): 2, ('user1', 'loggedin'): 1, ('user2', 'compiled'): 1})
```

Comment: In my opinion a nicer syntax would be counter.update([(1,2)]) rather than forcing an iterable with a comma. Not sure on the speed implications on constructing a list though. In any case, this solved my problem.