# How can I add items to collection.Counter? and then sort them into ASC?

Tags: python, collections, preprocessor, normalization, spam-prevention

At the moment I'm trying to process [`lingspam dataset`](http://www.aueb.gr/users/ion/) by counting the occurance of words in 600 files (400 emails and 200 spam emails). I've already made each word universal with the [`Porter Stemmer` Aglorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683932/porter-stemmer-algorithm-not-returning-the-expected-output-when-modified-into-d), I would also like for my result to be standardized across each file for further processing. But I'm unsure on how I can accomplish this..

**Resources thus far**

- [8.3. collections — Container datatypes](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
- [How to count co-ocurrences with collections.Counter() in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883194/how-to-count-co-ocurrences-with-collections-counter-in-python)
- [Bag of Words model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)

In order to get the output below I need to be able to add items that may not exist inside the file, in ascending order.

```
printing from ./../lingspam_results/spmsgb164.txt.out
[('money', 0, 'univers', 0,  'sales', 0)]
printing from ./../lingspam_results/spmsgb166.txt.out
[('money', 2, 'univers', 0,  'sales', 0)]
printing from ./../lingspam_results/spmsgb167.txt.out
[('money', 0, 'univers', 0,  'sales', 1)]
```

Which I then plan on converting into `vectors` using `numpy`.

```
[0,0,0]
[2,0,0]
[0,0,0]
```

instead of..

```
printing from ./../lingspam_results/spmsgb165.txt.out
[]
printing from ./../lingspam_results/spmsgb166.txt.out
[('univers', 2)]
printing from ./../lingspam_results/spmsgb167.txt.out
[('sale', 1)]
```

How can I standardize my results from the `Counter` module into `Ascending Order` (while also adding items to the Counter Result that may not exist from my `search_list`)? I've tried something already below that simply reads from each text file and creates a list based on the `search_list`.

```
import numpy as np, os
from collections import Counter

def parse_bag(directory, search_list):
    words = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(directory):
        for f in filenames:
            path = directory + "/" + f
            count_words(path, search_list)
    return;

def count_words(filename, search_list):
    textwords = open(filename, 'r').read().split()
    filteredwords = [t for t in textwords if t in search_list]
    wordfreq = Counter(filteredwords).most_common(5)
    print "printing from " + filename
    print wordfreq

search_list = ['sale', 'univers', 'money']
parse_bag("./../lingspam_results", search_list)
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean "in ascending order"? You're not talking about the alphabetical order of your `search_list` words, are you?

Comment: Or you want each file's items sorted by their overall frequency across all files?

Comment: I'm talking about the result from `wordfreq = Counter(filteredwords).most_common(5)` being in `ascending order` instead of the order of which word occurs the most.

Comment: Like you want to sort the whole `(count, word)` values ascending? I don't see how your first example above is in ascending order. Also, is it a typo that they're all in one big tuple? I don't see how your code can produce that output.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that myself in my example, I've edited it. And my code can't produce that output, thats pretty much the reason I'm asking, because I'd like to know whether or not that output I would like to know if it is possible. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, it sounds like your requirements are that you want the same words in a consistent ordering across all files, with counts. This should do it for you:

```
def count_words(filename, search_list):
    textwords = open(filename, 'r').read().split()
    filteredwords = [t for t in textwords if t in search_list]
    counter = Counter(filteredwords)
    for w in search_list:
        counter[w] += 0        # ensure exists
    wordfreq = sorted(counter.items())
    print "printing from " + filename
    print wordfreq

search_list = ['sale', 'univers', 'money']
```

sample output:

```
printing from ./../lingspam_results/spmsgb164.txt.out
[('money', 0), ('sale', 0), ('univers', 0)]
printing from ./../lingspam_results/spmsgb166.txt.out
[('money', 2), ('sale', 0), ('univers', 0)]
printing from ./../lingspam_results/spmsgb167.txt.out
[('money', 0), ('sale', 1), ('univers', 0)]
```

I don't think you want to use `most_common` at all since you specifically don't want the contents of each file to affect the ordering or list length.

Comment: Perfect thanks! :) your answer in combination with jsbueno is exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: I guess I'm still confused about your requirements, then, but glad we could help! Using the sort recipe from jsbueno's answer, I get `[u:0, s:0, m:0]`, `[m:2, u:0, s:0]`, and `[s:1, u:0, m:0]`, which I don't see how you could convert into a standardized vector format.

Comment: I've added an answer on how I got into `[4,0,0]` for example. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The call `Counter(filteredwords)` as you use in your example can count all the words, just like you intend - what it does not do is to give you the most used ones - i.e., there is no "most_common" method -
For that you have to reprocess all items in the counter, in order to have a sequence of tuples contaning the (frequency, word), and sort that:

```
def most_common(counter, n=5):
     freq = sorted (((value ,item) for item, value in counter.viewitems() ), reverse=True)
     return [item[1] for item in freq[:n]]
```

Comment: Eh? Are you saying this isn't the right thing?: [Counter.most_common](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.Counter.most_common)

Comment: Thanks :) it works pretty well, made some adjustments based on the information I want. But its a start. How can I add items to the result of `Counter(x)` from `filteredwords` (if `filterwords` only contains 0, 1 or 2 words from the `search_list`)?

Answer (score 1):

Combination of both jsbueno and Mu Mind

```
def count_words_SO(filename, search_list):
    textwords = open(filename, 'r').read().split()
    filteredwords = [t for t in textwords if t in search_list]
    counter = Counter(filteredwords)
    for w in search_list:
        counter[w] += 0        # ensure exists
    wordfreq = number_parse(counter)
    print "printing from " + filename
    print wordfreq

def number_parse(counter, n=5):
     freq = sorted (((value ,item) for item, value in counter.viewitems() ),    reverse=True)
     return [item[0] for item in freq[:n]]
```

Comes out with, just a little more work and I'll have it ready for a `Neurel  Network` thanks all :)

```
printing from ./../lingspam_results/spmsgb19.txt.out
[0, 0, 0]
printing from ./../lingspam_results/spmsgb2.txt.out
[4, 0, 0]
printing from ./../lingspam_results/spmsgb20.txt.out
[10, 0, 0]
```

Comment: So you don't want your neural network to have a dedicated input for each word? i.e., you want a file with 100 'univers', 2 'money', 0 'sale' to be exactly equivalent to a file with 100 'money', 2 'sale', 0 'univers'?